# Coredata relationship entity creation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a question about the coredata relationship.

Essentially, if I have 1 entity called i.e parent and the other entity which it has a relationship with is children and it is inverse.

If I create the parent entity, will it create the children entity as well? I 've set the "parentchildrenrelationship" to optional but it looks like every time I create the parent entity, it creates the children entity.

Is that something normal ? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by children entity?

Comment: Sorry typo meant parent has relationship with children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not normal. Are you sure you're not creating the children entity otherwise? Just because you create one entity does not mean it creates the entities that it is referencing.

Comment: Hmm going through code. This is weird because this is the first time am experiencing this.

Comment: Okay got it. Stupid me. Was some test code lying around. ha and been scratching my head for a quite a while now.

Comment: It happens to all of us. Less, though, if we can admit it :)

Answer (score 1):

Core Data should *not* automatically create entities to fulfill relationships, especially if the relationship is optional. The value of `children` should either be `nil` (for a one-to-one relationship) or an empty NSSet or NSArray (for a one-to-many relationship, depending on ordering) for a newly created parent entity.